# How to find whom a registrar is reselling?

Tags: domains, whois

In case a domain is registered not with an ICANN accredited registrar and only the reseller is mentioned in the whois, how can I find out whom is the reseller actually reselling? For example, whois record for 24creation.com has it that the domain has been registered with fc2.com, but the latter doesn't seem to be an ICANN accredited one, so it must be reselling someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to http://whois.domaintools.com/
2. Search for the domain you're interested in.
3. Click the 'Registration' tab and look for the 'ICANN Registrar':

[image: ICANN Registrar]

In this case, the domain is being sold through [enom](http://www.enom.com/) (who *is* ICANN accredited).